# use of tikzdevice in RMarkdown with beamer output

Tags: r-markdown, beamer, tikzdevice

I was wondering whether `tikzdevice` package can be used for producing R plots in RMarkdown, to be exported to a beamer presentation.

I would have thought that the solution I am looking for might be similar to the example with Sweave on page 15 of the [tikzdevice manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tikzDevice/vignettes/tikzDevice.pdf).

What I have tried, without knowing exactly what I am doing, is to amend Yihui's example from the RMarkdown book:

````
---
title: "Habits"
author: John Doe
date: March 22, 2005
output: beamer_presentation
---

# In the morning

## Getting up

- Turn off alarm
- Get out of bed

---

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='tex'}
require(tikzDevice)
tikz(console=TRUE)
plot(sin, -pi, 2*pi, main="A Stand Alone TikZ Plot")
dummy <- dev.off()
```
````

Unfortunatly, this does not result in the tikz plot being rendered in the beamer presentation. Does anyone see how this can be achieved? Thanks.

Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few problems in what you wrote.  LaTeX needs to be told to use the `tikz` package; and in `knitr`, you use `results='asis'` instead of `results='tex'`.  Finally, you would need to tell `tikz()` what size figure to use.

However, rather than fix those things, it's easier to tell `knitr` to handle everything, by using the `'tikz'` graphics device.  So this works:

````
---
title:  Demo with dev='tikz'
output: beamer_presentation
---

## A Tikz plot

```{r echo=FALSE, dev='tikz'}
plot(sin, -pi, 2*pi, main="A Stand Alone TikZ Plot")
```
````

Comment: Thanks, @user2554330. That is brilliant. Also, your reference to `knitr` made me realise that I had been reading in the wrong places: Details on the graphics engine turn out to be documented in the [knitr graphics manual](https://yihui.name/knitr/), and not in the `R Markdown` documentation, as I had presumed.